# Hide unresolved import error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I work with the Python plugin for Eclipse : PyDev on Linux and I'm writing a cross-platform application.

In this application, I have the following lines code :

```
try :
    from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
    appdata_path = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0)
except :
    appdata_path = os.environ['APPDATA']
```

PyDev show me 2 errors :

```
Unresolved import: shell
Unresolved import: shellcon
```

These errors appears because the `pywin32` extensions aren't installed on my system and I can't install it because there are windows extensions, not linux.

Is it have a way to hide or ignore (only) these errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click Ctl + 1 on the failing import line and select @UnresolvedImport error

or manually, make like this:

```
import Afailure #@UnresolvedImport
```